# Multiple DBs on a same aws_rds_cluster_instance

Tags: amazon-rds, terraform

I am creating an aws_rds_cluster via terraform with a single DB, now I Need to create a secondary database on the same aws_rds_cluster.

How would I do that then?

My first impulse was to define `database_name` as `["db1", "db2"]`, which, after looking at the documentation, I discovered as not being supported.

This is the code that creates the single "db1" instance and works.

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  cluster_identifier        = "${var.env}-my-project"
  availability_zones        = "${var.azs}"
  database_name             = "${var.database_name}"
  master_username           = "${var.user}"
  master_password           = "${var.password}"
  backup_retention_period   = 5
  preferred_backup_window   = "07:00-09:00"
  db_subnet_group_name      = "${aws_db_subnet_group.subnet_group.name}"
  engine                    = "aurora"
  skip_final_snapshot       = false
  final_snapshot_identifier = "final"
  vpc_security_group_ids    = ["${data.aws_security_group.sg_mysql.id}"]
  db_cluster_parameter_group_name = "${aws_rds_cluster_parameter_group.parameter_group.name}"
  tags = "${merge(var.tags, map("Name", var.tag_name, "environment", var.env))}"
}
```

Now, how would I add a second db schema on the same machine?

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/1298

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same problem and figured out the solution.

So in order to create multiple databases on the same aws_rds_cluster_instance you can use the [postgresql Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql/latest) next to the `aws_rds_cluster` and `aws_rds_cluster_instance` resources.

Here's an example Terraform configuration with multiple databases per one aws_rds_cluster_instance:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    postgresql = {
      source  = "cyrilgdn/postgresql"
      version = "~> 1.20.0"
    }
  }
}

locals {
  db_username = "jason"
  db_password = "super_secure"
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "aurora" {
  cluster_identifier              = "multidb"
  engine_mode                     = "provisioned"
  apply_immediately               = true
  engine                          = "aurora-postgresql"
  database_name                   = "db_0"
  engine_version                  = "15.3"
  master_username                 = local.db_username
  master_password                 = local.db_password
  preferred_backup_window         = "09:00-10:00"         // time is in UTC
  preferred_maintenance_window    = "Sun:11:00-Sun:12:00" // time is in UTC
  enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports = ["postgresql"]
  deletion_protection             = true
  final_snapshot_identifier       = "multidb-final"
  serverlessv2_scaling_configuration {
    max_capacity = 2.0
    min_capacity = 0.5
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "aurora" {
  cluster_identifier  = aws_rds_cluster.aurora.id
  instance_class      = "db.serverless"
  engine              = aws_rds_cluster.aurora.engine
  engine_version      = aws_rds_cluster.aurora.engine_version
  apply_immediately   = true
  publicly_accessible = false
}

provider "postgresql" {
  host     = aws_rds_cluster_instance.aurora.endpoint
  database = aws_rds_cluster.aurora.database_name
  username = local.db_username
  password = local.db_password
}

resource "postgresql_database" "db_1" {
  name  = "db_1"
  owner = local.db_username
}

resource "postgresql_database" "db_2" {
  name  = "db_2"
  owner = local.db_username
}

resource "postgresql_database" "db_3" {
  name  = "db_3"
  owner = local.db_username
}

resource "postgresql_database" "db_4" {
  name  = "db_4"
  owner = local.db_username
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[aws_rds_cluster_instance](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/rds_cluster_instance.html)

> Amazon Aurora you do not designate a primary and subsequent replicas. Instead, you simply add RDS Instances and Aurora manages the replication. You can use the count meta-parameter to make multiple instances and join them all to the same RDS Cluster, or you may specify different Cluster Instance resources with various instance_class sizes.

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "rds_cluster_instance" {
    count                 = "${length(var.azs)}"
    identifier            = "${aws_rds_cluster.my_cluster.id}-instance-${count.index}"
    cluster_identifier    = "${aws_rds_cluster.my_cluster.id}"
    instance_class        = "${var.db_instance_class}"
}
```

---

## Multiple database schema

RDS CreateDBInstance API call only accept 1 schema as far as I understand as in the [github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/1298), hence accordingly Terraform could also only specify 1 schema. As in linked #3122 and #3653, once the cluster/instance is created, then use corresponding provider + database e.g. [MySQL Provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/mysql/index.html) should be the way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're asking how to add a second database schema to the cluster rather than another instance but it would be useful if @kiosia could edit the question to clarify this.

Comment: yep. edited the question (the word 'schema' was escaping my mind at the time), thanks!